# How to pass a command line from a shell script to command line argument for a C program?

Tags: c

I have difficulties passing command lines from a shell script to command lines argument in a C program. For now I can only pass command lines as parameters one by one in my program.

```
int main(int argc, char ** argv) {

int pipefd[2]; // Array for pipe

pid_t processChild; // Id fork

pipe(pipefd); // Demarrage du pipe avec l'array

if (processChild = fork()==0){
    close(1); // stdout close
    close(pipefd[0]); // close read
    dup2(pipefd[1],1); // Copy writting to write in pipe

    int d = execvp(argv[1], &argv[1]); // Exec command in param

    if (d == -1){ // Verif
        printf("Erreur \n");
        exit(0);
    }
}
else{
    char tmp[32]; //  Tampon for the pipe read
    int nbrBytes;
    int totBytes;
    close(pipefd[1]); // Closing writting

    system("echo --- RESULT ---"); // Show result
    while((nbrBytes = read(pipefd[0], tmp, sizeof(tmp))) > 0){ // Reading pipe file with tampon
        totBytes += nbrBytes;
        write(1, tmp, nbrBytes);
    }

    close(pipefd[0]); // Close read
    exit(0); // Close program
}
return 0;}
```

I just want to execute my program with a shell script as a parameter, the program get the commands from the script then they're executed by the child processus and then the parent processus show the result. ^^

Comment: Well, did you try argv[2], 3, 4...?

Comment: Perhaps I don't understand what you want to do...  If I compile your program as pg1, and invoke it as follows: pg1 echo one two three, the output is --- RESULT ---
one two three
... so pg1 invokes "echo" with arguments of: one two three.  Is this not what you want?

Comment: @Mendo - Your program already works _with a shell script as a parameter_ provided that it is executable and has an appropriate path if needed.

Comment: I have an error when I try...

Comment: @TonyB This is what I want but instead of pg1 echo one two three, I want pg1 myscript.
And it executes all the commands that are in myscript and shows the results one by one

Comment: @Mendo pg1 myscript should work fine, assuming it is correctly written, and it is executable.  My example shows the invocation in your program is working, so it you have a problem, it is elsewhere.